# How can i speed up this django orm generated query?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a Movie table and a Genre table and a MovieGenre table to say what genres a movie has.

The django orm came up with this query when i'm trying to get Movies which have at least all of the genres a target movie has in common.

```
SELECT "movies_movie"."id", "movies_movie"."imdb_id", ..etc..   "movies_movie"."last_ingested_on", 
COUNT("movies_movie"."id") AS "count", 
COUNT("movies_moviegenre"."genre_id") AS "genres_count" 
FROM "movies_movie" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "movies_moviegenre" ON ( "movies_movie"."id" = "movies_moviegenre"."movie_id" ) INNER JOIN "movies_moviegenre" T4 ON ( "movies_movie"."id" = T4."movie_id" ) 
INNER JOIN "movies_moviegenre" T6 ON ( "movies_movie"."id" = T6."movie_id" ) 
WHERE ("movies_movie"."last_ingested_on" IS NOT NULL 
AND NOT ("movies_movie"."imdb_id" = 'tt0111161' ) 
AND "movies_movie"."type" = 'feature' 
AND "movies_movie"."certification" = 'R' 
AND T4."genre_id" = 1 AND T6."genre_id" = 10 ) 
GROUP BY "movies_movie"."id", "movies_movie"."imdb_id", "movies_movie"."movie", "movies_movie"."type", "movies_movie"."year", "movies_movie"."tagline", "movies_movie"."plot", "movies_movie"."runtime", "movies_movie"."rating", "movies_movie"."certification", "movies_movie"."budget", "movies_movie"."box_office_revenue", "movies_movie"."poster_url", "movies_movie"."trailer_url", "movies_movie"."mood_data", "movies_movie"."created_on", "movies_movie"."modified_on", "movies_movie"."last_ingested_on" HAVING COUNT("movies_moviegenre"."genre_id") >= 2 
ORDER BY "count" DESC
```

Can you see anything that could be causing it to be slow, it's taking 1107.26499557 ms which isn't acceptable. Thanks in advance

explain output: http://explain.depesz.com/s/lEv

Comment: Maybe denormalize counts and store them in the tables and update them every time content is added, thus making looking up the count a simpler SELECT operation?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa are you saying have another table with columns, targetmovie, movie, genreInCommonCount. If so that table would be massive (100+ million rows) for each targetmovie/movie combination.

Answer (score 0):

Not a SQL expert but this double inner join looks strange to me, strange as in they are equivalent.

`LEFT OUTER JOIN "movies_moviegenre" ON ( "movies_movie"."id" = "movies_moviegenre"."movie_id" ) INNER JOIN "movies_moviegenre" T4 ON ( "movies_movie"."id" = T4."movie_id" ) 
INNER JOIN "movies_moviegenre" T6 ON ( "movies_movie"."id" = T6."movie_id" )`

Said that what about adding an index for columns of your where clause? I'm looking at these in particular which looks like good index candidates:

`AND "movies_movie"."type" = 'feature' 
AND "movies_movie"."certification" = 'R' 
AND T4."genre_id" = 1 AND T6."genre_id" = 10 )`

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/optimization/#use-standard-db-optimization-techniques

Comment: i should have mentioned i have indexes on movie.type and movie.certification

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i wasn't specific enough in my SELECT

```
SELECT "movies_movie"."id", "movies_movie"."imdb_id", ..etc..
```

i was selecting every column in the movie table, some columns contain alot of data. after changing this using djanog's queryset .only() method time dropped from 1000ms to 200ms. a good start

edit:

it was one field with alot of data in it actually, so the real solution is to put that in its own table.